# Play a sound before opening an URL

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

### Explanation

I'm having a problem when calling an action before opening App Store to rate my game. The sound won't be played. I've seen a game in which it worked. Am I doing anything wrong?

### Code

```
func rateGame(){

    let appIDString = "375380948"
    let reviewsURLString = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software&mt=8&id=\(appIDString)"
    let reviewsURL = NSURL(string: reviewsURLString)

    clickSoundFX()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(reviewsURL!)
}

func clickSoundFX(){
    self.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("buttonClick.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Comment: Have you tried testing it without opening the URL?

Comment: Yes, it's working with many others functions.

Comment: Perhaps you need to set a timer for a few seconds before calling `openURL()`

Comment: that's a way, but I don't get why it doesn't work as it's now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch `clickSoundFX()` and after you call:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(reviewsURL!)
```

your game start to make an action to play a simple sound but right after all the app going in `applicationDidEnterBackground` due to open an external url: in this exact moment all your game going in paused mode so you can't do any action.

A safe way to do your code is to make a pause sequence after your sound and check the completion like this:

```
let wait = SKAction.SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)
let sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("buttonClick.mp3")
let seq = SKAction.sequence([sound,wait])
self.runAction(seq,completion: {
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(reviewsURL!)
})
```

Comment: That's what I did. Thank you for the explanation!! =)